# Compare Two Strings And Capture Different Values

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is it possible to compare two strings and find values not present in both? For example,

String 1: `email123@prod.com email234@prod.com`

String 2: `email123@prod.com email234@prod.com email345@prod.com email890@prod.com`

Result: `email345@prod.com; email890@prod.com`

Is it possible to use NOT IN or NOT EXISTS to capture those values.

Thanks for any direction.

Comment: No.  `NOT IN` and `NOT EXISTS` do not do what you want at the string level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `string_split()` and aggregation:

```
select string_agg(coalesce(s1.value, s2.value), '; ')
from string_split(@string1, ' ') s1 full join
     string_split(@string2, ' ') s2
     on s1.value = s2.value
where s1.value is null or s2.value is null;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=aa6ae6b834146237c0cdd6610603ea8f) is a db<>fiddle.